# React native TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating ‘nativeImagePicler.launchImageLibrary’)

Tags: react-native, expo

hello i have a problem with my expo app
the app was working before 2 days and suddenly the app cannot use “image picker” like it was
i trying expo image picker (that work before 2 days)
and now because this error i try the “react-native-image-picker” and it also not working and get the same error:
react native image picker : TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating ‘nativeImagePicler.launchImageLibrary’)

expo image picker : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘result.assets[0]’)

the code not change since then so its not the problem
i think its something about the sdk or module or build or some configuration of the expo (maybe i change and forgot to check)

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "lottery",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/292e68aa-3480-4c01-b697-6672a8d899fc"
    },
    "slug": "lottery",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/lottery-icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/lottery-background.png",
      "plugins": [
        [
          "expo-image-picker",
          {
            "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
          }
        ],
        [
          "expo-build-properties",
          {
            "android": {
              "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.liors.lottery.first.project",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/lottery-background.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "292e68aa-3480-4c01-b697-6672a8d899fc"
      }
    }
  }
}


Screenshot_206





Reply
You will receive notifications because you created this topic.
Suggested Topics

URL Scheme not recognized IOS 
0
Expo Development Tools
1d

EAS build: The application’s Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleShortVersionString 
13
```

Comment: I think ```plugins``` shouldn't be within splash.

Comment: first of all you right :) 
but it still not working
give the same error

Comment: What is your SDK version? Are you using the `expo-image-picker` library?

Comment: Hey the sdk version is 47. And yes i using the expo image picker. Its weird but it fixed by itself... yesterday it gave me the error but today in the morning i run thus development server and its actually working as was before and i didnt change something